# How to check if command has matched output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I have a BASH script that will create a bootable USB drive with GRUB.

The current problem is that the script will continue even if no USB drive is inserted. This will cause the user to continue without any safety measures especially if the user is new to command line.

I want a command that will check if the output is either sdb, sdc, sdd, sde or sdf. If the output matches either sdb, sdc, sdd, sde or sdf then the script will continue. If none of the output matches sdb, sdc, sdd, sde or sdf, then the script will exit. The current command below does not work. I didn't post all of the code because I think only this is important.

The command with a quote is the command that will check for the output

```
"if [[ $(lsblk | grep -w "sdb\|sdc\|sdd\|sde\|sdf") ]]; then
    echo "No USB drive found. Please insert one."
fi"

echo -e "--------------------------------" | lolcat
echo
lsblk | grep -w "sdb\|sdc\|sdd\|sde\|sdf" | lolcat
echo
echo -e "--------------------------------" | lolcat
echo

echo -e "Which pendrive listed above do you want to install MMI on?" | lolcat

echo

echo -e "Input example:" | lolcat
echo -e "(sdx) without brackets" | lolcat
read -p ":" INSTALLATION_DRIVE

echo

if [ -z "${INSTALLATION_DRIVE}" ]
then
    echo -e "Invalid input, quitting..."
    exit 1
fi
```

Sorry for the lolcat! Just want to make the script colourful!

Comment: `The current command below does not work.` what is happening instead? Can you show the output of `lsblk` and show us why it didn't work?

Comment: @Inian The command doesn't work because even if no USB device is inserted, the script continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t provide enough details for a complete answer, however the `if` condition is wrong. What you probably want to do is

```
if ! lsblk | egrep -qw "sdb|sdc|sdd|sde|sdf"; then
    echo "No USB drive found. Please insert one."
fi
```

Please note the presence of `!`  and the `-q` option, and the absence of `[[ ]]`, `$()`...

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide the complete script. Actually I just need a command that will continue if the output matches either sdb, sdc, sdd, sde or sdf and exit if the output doesn't match. The codes after that doesn't effect the particular command even if it is there or not.